# Sails.js / Waterline - Modify the createdAt and updatedAt throws an error : Anchor does not support functions yet

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I tried to implement a timestamp for createdAt and updated but I can't make it work. Everytime it throws the following error : Anchor does not support functions yet!

In **Entity.js** :

```
 module.exports = {

    autoCreatedAt: 'created_ts',
    autoUpdatedAt: 'updated_ts',
    attributes: {

        entity_name : {
            type : 'string'     
        },
        creationDate: {
            columnName: 'created_ts',
            type: 'datetime',
            defaultsTo: function() {return new Date().getTime;}
        },
        updateDate: {
            columnName: 'updated_ts',
            type: 'datetime',
            defaultsTo: function() {return new Date().getTime;}
        },
        toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.createdAt;
            delete obj.updatedAt;
            return obj;
        }

    },
    beforeUpdate:function(values,next) {
        values.updateDate = new Date().getTime;
        next();
    }

 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 errors here.

1. `getTime` is a function so if you want to use it you should use it like that `new Date().getTime()` but in this case value you are interested in is simply `new Date()`
2. method `toJSON` shouldn't be in attributes. And name of deleted atributes aren't correct right now.

So your code after fixes:

```
 module.exports = {

    autoCreatedAt: 'created_ts',
    autoUpdatedAt: 'updated_ts',
    attributes: {

        entity_name : {
            type : 'string'     
        },
        creationDate: {
            columnName: 'created_ts',
            type: 'datetime',
            defaultsTo: function() {return new Date();}
        },
        updateDate: {
            columnName: 'updated_ts',
            type: 'datetime',
            defaultsTo: function() {return new Date();}
        }
    },
    beforeUpdate:function(values,next) {
        values.updateDate = new Date();
        next();
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.creationDate;
        delete obj.updateDate;
        return obj;
   }

 };
```